# 403 Forbidden after vhosts.conf include

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2, wamp, virtualhost

This morning all was well in the installation "Zend Framework http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html", **after** I include the "conf / extra / httpd -vhosts.conf "Virtual host could no longer access my local area and also can not access the Virtual host.

message:

*Apache / 2.4.9 (Win64) PHP / 5.5.12 Server at Port 80 platform.localhost*

**httpd.conf**

```
<Directory />
     AllowOverride none
     Require all denied
</ Directory>

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride FileInfo
     Require local
</ Directory>
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost.platform
    ServerAlias localhost.platform
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/platform/public"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/platform/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.sh
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**etc / hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost.platform
```

Zend installed by composer Windowns using PowerShell
Thank you.

apache_error.log

> [Sat Sep 13 19:19:32.833823 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2140:tid
>   400] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the
>   server.
>
> [Sat Sep 13 19:19:34.839937 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6108:tid
>   316] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
>
> [Sat Sep 13 19:19:34.886940 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2140:tid
>   400] AH00430: Parent: Child process 6108 exited successfully.
>
> AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot
>   [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist AH00112:
>   Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does
>   not exist
>
> [Sat Sep 13 19:19:37.902112 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1272:tid
>   400] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming
>   normal operations
>
> [Sat Sep 13 19:19:37.903112 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1272:tid
>   400] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
>
> [Sat Sep 13 19:19:37.903112 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1272:tid 400]
>   AH00094: Command line:
>   'c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\httpd.exe -d
>   C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
>
> [Sat Sep 13 19:19:37.906113 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1272:tid
>   400] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5856
>
> AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot
>   [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist AH00112:
>   Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does
>   not exist AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot
>   [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist AH00112:
>   Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does
>   not exist
>
> [Sat Sep 13 19:19:39.532206 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5856:tid
>   316] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

Comment: `C: / wamp / www / platform / public` **I really hope those are not spaces.**

Comment: `platform.localhost ServerName` this is wrong should be the opposite. Start by editing your question and posting the data as they show to you with out the spaces and other things you've changed as it only makes it harder for us to help you. **Also check the error_log of your server and post what it says.**

Comment: 403 Forbidden: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost.platform Port 80, ok thanks for attention

Comment: `403 forbidden exception will occur only when you set wrong access permissions to your folder`. can you access index.html from the folder "C:/wamp/www" on your browser by http://localhost ?